# Spring Data REST: sort parameter is ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE project with Spring Data JPA and Spring Data REST. It seems that the `sort` parameter in the REST endpoint is ignored (but the same repository method do work in a unit test).
The repository is the following:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "orders", path = "orders")
public interface OrderRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<OrderEntity, Integer>, OrderRepositoryExtended {

@Query(value = "FROM OrderEntity a WHERE "
                + " (a.orderDateTime BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo) AND"
                + " ("
                + "  :searchTerm IS NULL OR"
                + "  (LOWER(a.customer.companyName) LIKE '%' || LOWER(:searchTerm) || '%') OR"
                + "  (LOWER(a.orderCode) LIKE '%' || LOWER(:searchTerm) || '%')"
                + " )"
)
Page<OrderEntity> findByOrderDateTimeBetweenAndSearchTerm(
        @RequestParam(name = "dateFrom")
        @Param("dateFrom")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
            LocalDateTime dateFrom,

        @RequestParam(name = "dateTo")
        @Param("dateTo")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
            LocalDateTime dateTo,

        @RequestParam(name = "searchTerm")
        @Param("searchTerm")
            String searchTerm,

        Pageable pageable);
```

}

The entity (edited) is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ORDERS")
@Data @NoArgsConstructor
@Cacheable(false)
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "ID_ORDER")
    @JsonProperty("id_order")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "DATE_ORDER")
    @JsonProperty("date_order")
    private LocalDateTime orderDateTime;

}
```

When I try to invoke it using the exported REST endpoint, for example:

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/orders/search/findByOrderDateTimeBetweenAndSearchTerm?dateFrom=2018-01-01T00:00:00&dateTo=2018-12-01T00:00:00&sort=orderDateTime&searchTerm=O-2018

The `sort` parameter is ignored as you can see in the generated query (edited for clarity):

```
select orderentit0_.id_order as id_order1_21_
...
from t_orders orderentit0_ 
cross join t_customers customeren1_ 
where 
    orderentit0_.id_customer=customeren1_.id_customer and 
    (orderentit0_.date_order between ? and ?) and 
    (? is null or lower(customeren1_.company_name) like concat('%'
lower(?)
'%') or lower(orderentit0_.order_code) like concat('%'
lower(?)
'%')) limit ?
```

I've already tried simplifing the WHERE expression removing the LIKE conditions but with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to put sort parameter at the end of the url? And did you try another field for the sort? I made a simple demo example and it works for me

Comment: I tried putting sort in front and at the end of the URL; other repositories in the project works fine with similar situation. I never got working sort by a LocalDateTime field tho.

Comment: Works like a charm for me with LocalDateTime. Try to make a simple example just with the sort. Btw. you can remove many unnecessary annotations from the find method. Just @Param is mandatory

Answer (score 1):

The 'exported' name of your property is `date_order`. It should be used this way not only in json requests but also in request parameters.

```
@Column(name = "DATE_ORDER")
@JsonProperty("date_order")
private LocalDateTime orderDateTime;
```

Try this way:

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/orders/search/findByOrderDateTimeBetweenAndSearchTerm?dateFrom=2018-01-01T00:00:00&dateTo=2018-12-01T00:00:00&sort=date_order&searchTerm=O-2018

( sort=**date_order** )

Comment: I tried that but the query produced by Hibernate is still without the order by parameter.